# Flatmap merging an internal iterator

Tags: scala

I'm trying to convert an `Iterator[String]` to `Iterator[CustomClass]`, where `CustomClass` is self-explanatory and doesn't need to have much detail here.

The workflow is:

```
Iterator[String] -> Iterator[Array[Byte]] -> Iterator[CustomClass]
```

What I have so far:

```
def extractAsCustomClass(strings: Iterator[String]): Iterator[CustomClass] = {
  val byteArrayIt = strings.flatMap(toByteArrayIterator)
  val customClassIt = byteArrayIt.flatMap(toCustomClassIterator)
  customClassIt
}

private def toByteArrayIterator(data: String): Iterator[Array[Byte]] = { // converts to byte array }
private def toCustomClassIterator(blob: Array[Byte]): Iterator[CustomClass] = { // converts to custom class }
```

With this, my end result is an `Iterator[CustomClass]` that contains one element where all the input byte arrays were combined into one byte array. So if I call `extractAsCustomClass` with a String iterator that has two elements, the end result would be `Iterator[CustomClass]` which only has one, combined element.

Using the example above of an input String iterator with two elements, I instead want an `Iterator[CustomClass]` that contains two `CustomClass` elements, where each String has gone from

```
String -> Array[Byte] -> CustomClass
```

I've tried playing around with `map` and `flatMap` but it either creates iterators of iterators or a combined element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got yourself a little bit tangled up; it's way easier than you think it is! :-)

Remember that for some container type `C` holding items of type `A` (i.e. `C[A]`) if you want to get a `C[B]` (i.e. a container holding items of type `B`) then just supply **the way to get from `A` to `B` as the argument to `map`**. You don't need to worry about the outer container type `C` *at all*.

So in your case, the functions you need to supply would just be:

`private def toByteArray(data: String): Array[Byte]`

`private def toCustomClass(blob: Array[Byte]): CustomClass`

Notice how they don't mention `Iterator` anywhere. A great benefit - they're much more useful and re-usable as a result.

So for a complete worked (and working!) example:

```
case class CustomClass(foo: String)

private def toByteArray(data: String): Array[Byte] = {
  // converts to byte array
  data.getBytes
}

private def toCustomClass(blob: Array[Byte]): CustomClass = {
   // converts to custom class
   val s = new String(blob)
   CustomClass(s)
}
```

Now your extract function is just:

```
def extractAsCustomClass(strings: Iterator[String]): Iterator[CustomClass] = {
  val byteArrayIt = strings.map(toByteArray)
  val customClassIt = byteArrayIt.map(toCustomClass)
  customClassIt
}
```